# how to creat a histogram from two raster layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have two raster layer ( raster layer 1 and raster layer 2) that was made by kernel density. now, i want to create a graph that vertical axis shows the density of each cell in raster layer 1 and horizontal axis shows the density of each cell in raster layer 2.

How can i do that with arcgis?

Comment: Is it XY scatter plot you are talking about? If so you can create regular polygons using fish net, perform zonl statistics on both and pick what statistics to plot

Comment: Hi, thanks alot. but In the scatter plot I need to compare each single cell of one raster with the exact equivalent cell of the second raster. So I guess I need to have all cell values of both rasters in one table. how i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all cells for your analysis, first thing to check if rasters are identical in terms of extent and cell size. Go to layer properties and check if this is the case:

[image]
[image]

[You can convert rasters to point](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001200000007000000)

and join 2 tables using ObjectID if output is feature class in FGDB or FID if they are shapefiles. You also have to make sure NODATA areas are identic for both rasters.

I strongly discourage you to take this path, because outputs can be too big. For example shown you'll end up with 6020 * 6020 points (!)

To reduce I suggest [creating fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000) . Tick create label points. Specify number of columns, so that you'll end up with few 1000s points. Use you these points to [sample your rasters](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002s000000)